Why does this code work for adding spot colors in XeTeX?
I’m curious how adding colors (specifically spot colors) works in XeTeX at a low level, so I studied the
documentation for xespotcolor
and put together this minimal working example that typesets some text in a Pantone blue:
\catcode`#=12 \def\pdfspace{#20} \catcode`#=6
\special{pdf:obj @blue [/Separation /PANTONE\pdfspace285\pdfspace C
  /DeviceCMYK << /C0 [0 0 0 0] /FunctionType 2 /C1 [0.91 0.49 0 0] /Domain [0 1] /N 1 >>]}
\special{pdf:put @resources << /ColorSpace << /blue @blue >> >>}
Hello \special{color push spot blue 1}world\special{color pop}!
\bye


I’d like to know why \special{color push spot blue 1} works.
I tried looking at the documentation for
xdvipdfmx,
dvipdfmx and
dvipdfm
but couldn’t find any mention of a color command, let alone of color push spot.
The closest thing I could find was in
7.6.2 Color specials
of the dvips manual:

The ‘color’ special itself has three forms. The first is just ‘color’ followed by a color specification. In this case, the current global color is set to that color; the color stack must be empty when such a command is executed.
The second form is ‘color push’ followed by a color specification. This saves the current color on the color stack and sets the color to be that given by the color specification. This is the most common way to set a color.
The final version of the ‘color’ special is just ‘color pop’, with no color specification; this says to pop the color last pushed on the color stack from the color stack and set the current color to be that color.

7.6.1 Color specifications
explains that a color specification can be the name of a color model followed by some parameters:

What is a color specification? One of three things. First, it might be a PostScript procedure as defined in a PostScript header file. …
The second possibility is the name of a color model (initially, one of ‘rgb’, ‘hsb’, ‘cmyk’, or ‘gray’) followed by the appropriate number of parameters. When Dvips encounters such a macro, it sends out the parameters first, followed by the string created by prefixing ‘TeXcolor’ to the color model. Thus, the color specification ‘rgb 0.3 0.4 0.5’ would generate the PostScript code ‘0.3 0.4 0.5 TeXrgbcolor’ [I assume this is an error and it should say TeXcolorrgb].

This seems to suggest that spot blue 1 is transformed into blue 1 TeXcolorspot, which somehow does the right thing (something like sending out the PDF command /blue cs 1.0 scn I assume).
But what is this TeXcolorspot, and where is it defined?

how if works in dvips (if it works there which I don't know/remember) and how it works in dvipdfmx are too different things. dvipdfmx often supports specials that exist in dvips but adapts them (and it doesn't document everything it can do). You could ask on the dvipdfmx list for details.

spot colors are handled around here but it's not extensively documented and I didn't really try to follow all the code https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/trunk/texk/dvipdfm-x/pdfcolor.c#L302

Thanks! This looks like exactly what I need to read.
